# How Can I Display Value in Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to display a value in a drop-down whenever I edit content, but I don't know how can I show it. Can someone help me with this?

**Dropdown**

Here I have a dropdown that has the value of the country when I insert it to the database. But when I edit the drop-down, the country saved will be removed.

```php
{{ Form::select('from_location', trans('countries'), null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select where you From']) }}
```

**Update Controller**

```
$aircraftFlights = Aircraft::find($id);
$aircraftFlights ->destination= $request->input('destination');
$aircraftFlights ->save();
```

Comment: @AidenKaiser Summer is using Laravel Collectives HTML Forms and so the Laravel Docs do not include any info for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing null into field for current value.

Try this:

```
{{Form::select('from_location', trans('countries'), !empty($aircraftFlights) ? $aircraftFlights->destination : null ,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select where you From'])}}<br>
```

You can refer here for more details:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#drop-down-lists

Comment: you're the man really it works but how about this how can I display the value here   `<input type="datetime-local" name="arrival_time" class="form-control">` if it is a date and my variable here is `departure_time` which is the name of the table field

Comment: how can i display this variable on that input dattime sir @Josh , `$aircraftFlight->from_location`

Comment: Add this to the input: `value="{{ !empty($aircraftFlights) ? $aircraftFlights->departure_time : null"`

Comment: can you answer this sir ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604754/laravel-display-datetime-value-in-edit-form)

Comment: it is not working sir can you please answer the link i provided to you? i know u can help me

Answer (score 0):

`{{Form::select('from_location', trans('countries'),null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select where you From', 'value' => $your_value_here])}}`

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21587890)