# Laravel - Display DateTime Value in Edit Form

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I display my data which is a DateTime value in my edit form?

```
input="datetime-local."
```

Here's what my DateTime value looks like: `2018-04-02 04:04:00.`

I want it to display in this input:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="flight_date" class="form-control">
```

**my *$variable->data***

```
$aircraftFlight->flight_date
```

EDIT ***VAR DUMP***

> object(App\AircraftFlights)#527 (26) { ["table":protected]=>
>   string(16) "aircraft_flights" ["primaryKey"]=> string(2) "id"
>   ["timestamps"]=> bool(false) ["connection":protected]=> string(5)
>   "mysql" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=>
>   bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true)
>   ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=>
>   array(9) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["flight_number"]=> string(10) "AA-0000003"
>   ["iata_flight_number"]=> string(5) "ABCD2" ["flight_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-04-02 04:04:00" ["departure_time"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-05-04 01:59:00" ["arrival_time"]=> string(19) "2018-05-05
>   13:59:00" ["from_location"]=> string(11) "Afghanistan"
>   ["destination"]=> string(7) "Albania" ["aircraft_id"]=> int(1) }
>   ["original":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(1)
>   ["flight_number"]=> string(10) "AA-0000003" ["iata_flight_number"]=>
>   string(5) "ABCD2" ["flight_date"]=> string(19) "2018-04-02 04:04:00"
>   ["departure_time"]=> string(19) "2018-05-04 01:59:00"
>   ["arrival_time"]=> string(19) "2018-05-05 13:59:00"
>   ["from_location"]=> string(11) "Afghanistan" ["destination"]=>
>   string(7) "Albania" ["aircraft_id"]=> int(1) } ["changes":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) {
>   } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a date time picker with the input type as text and set the id to flight_date

have a look at this one:

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

There are a number around this is just the first I came across

Hope this helps

**Update**

This is the one that we use at work and I know it works

https://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Try that.

Comment: I hope this helps me but the code is like a long time ago it does not work on my end. :( it does not display the timepicker

Comment: @SummerWinter I have updated my answer if you would like to have a look.

Comment: lll just accept ur answer sir even tho the date picker will not help me to choose time :( . tho it will work the time will be a problem

Comment: Sorry summer that was the datepicker that we use I am trying to find the date time picker that we use

Comment: Yes sir, but if ever you can help me with mu current code that would be great thanks

Comment: sir i've solved the problem just by changing the date format and adding strtotime and inputting the {{$variable->dataname}} hope this will help u sir.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this resource by mdn. the date input type format is YYYY-MM-DD

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

```
<input type="date" value="value="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($team->portfolio_at)->format('Y-m-d') }}"
``
```

Answer (score 1):

try using carbon to format date:

`<input type="datetime-local" name="flight_date" class="form-control" value="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($aircraftFlight->flight_date)->format('yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm')}}">`

> Note: type="datetime-local" is not supported in Firefox, Safari or Internet Explorer 12 (or earlier).

Comment: there is no error but the value is not showing why is that

Comment: try adding this static value `2018-12-12T14:22`, if it doesn't work, then `type="datetime-local" ` is not supported in your browser.

Comment: you see im trying to edit this input .. do you get me sir?

Comment: that is why i need to get the stored value in the database

Comment: datetime-local is supported that is why i can use it and save data in it what i dont have is the update.. when i want to edit the date .. nothing shows uop

Comment: **update** when I insert **2018-12-12T14:22** the input field datetime-local has shown a value but the other code does not display any value

Comment: on my page the input field date time local looks like this **dd/mm/yyyy -- -- --**  , your updated code is still not working sir :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184660/discussion-between-capt-teemo-and-summer-winter).

Answer (score 0):

Put your variable on input type text value

```
<input type="text" name="flight_date" class="form-control" value="{{ $aircraftFlight->flight_date }}">
```

You can use php date() function to format your variable here is the link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

format into this

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($aircraftFlight->flight_date))
```

Comment: it does not display my stored value in database

Comment: well if i input ut to type text then it will receive an error because in its datatype is **dateTime**

Comment: @SummerWinter can you show me var_dump of your $aircraftFlight variable

Comment: @SummerWinter have a good look of answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843407/how-can-i-set-a-value-for-the-input-type-datetime-local

Comment: @SummerWinter try formatting your date something like this date('Y-m-dTH:i', $aircraftFlight->flight_date);

Comment: okay,, so how can i implement it with the input itself? how is the syntax should be?

Comment: @SummerWinter try this <input type="datetime-local" name="flight_date" class="form-control" value="{{ date('Y-m-dTH:i', $aircraftFlight->flight_date) }}">

Comment: error gives me **A non well formed numeric value encountered **

Comment: it has an error sir @Paul , **A non well formed numeric value encountered**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184659/discussion-between-paul-and-summer-winter).